# SwiftUI TextField customisation in WatchOS for removing emoji option

Tags: textfield, swiftui, watchos-6

I am trying to add a text input field using SwiftUI TextField in watchOs 6.1. 
I am getting following three options for providing inputs. i.e. Voice recorder, scribble pad and emoji option as shown in screen shot.

[image: Click here for screenshot]

I need only voice recorder option alone. How to remove the scribble pad and emoji option from TextField?